# Limiting login attempts based on IP - good idea?

Tags: security, authentication, passwords, ip

A client of mine has a site where you login with just a password (no user name). There are no users, but instead there's a user class system. So the admin class has a certain password, editor class different password etc. When you log in, your user class is detected based on the password.

I know this looks quite insecure, but the client thinks it's simple and he likes it that way (i didn't build the initial site)

Is it a good idea to limit the number of login attempts per IP, to let's say 5 per hour? Would this significantly increase the security? I believe it's very hard for an attacker to get a new IP again and again

Comment: What happens if 2 users select the same password? or is a user not able to select his/her own password? Also, it is rather easy for an attacker to change the IP.

Comment: The passwords are all set by the site admin, there should be no clashes

Comment: Adding some kind of delay between login attempts, even a short static delay would at least make brute force attacks less feasible or, at minimum, more costly with regards to time.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a good idea, it's quite simple to an attacker change it's IP, so this will not give you extra security. But when you're behind a corporative network all the machines will have the same external address, so in practice you'll probably get some problems with you legitimate users.

the best solution to improve the security is to create some kind of whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no harm limiting number of login attempts per hour. It would make it a little more secure, but keep in mind that it's rather easy to use proxy servers these days to use a different ip address.

Also you could think this reversed. If your client is always using this from same ip, you could make IP whitelist insted of blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

It would increase security, but not as much as introducing a username parameter. Every attempt an attacker makes is targeting all users (classes), drastically increasing chances there will be a correct guess each time and you also have no way of knowing which of your classes is being targeted.

Also your current approach prohibits the use of [salted hashes](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) which can increase security as each password in your system will be hashed differently. This is because there is no username record available for the appropriate salt to be selected, which in itself will weaken security.

### What you should do

You should introduce a username field - to keep it simple this could be the name of the class.

Log both the remote IP and username of every attempt and you should rate limit the number of attempts allowed from the same IP address or against the same username.

If more than your set threshold of bad attempts occur from either the same IP or against the same username then you should throttle responses by introducing an artificial delay that would hinder the attack. This delay should be across all threads if simultaneous attempts occur from the same IP or against the same username - these requests should then be processed in serial as this would slow a brute force attempt that utilises multiple threads with simultaneous HTTP connections.

Your suggestion of limiting of 5 per hour would only upset the most casual attacker. As other answers have mentioned, getting a new IP would be a trivial task for a determined attacker and something more than IP would be needed to properly secure your system and reduce the scope of the attack to a single resource (user) at any one time.